# Inconsistent results while using elastic searchafter with point in time in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

We have an elastic search cluster that has multiple indices. In the cluster, we have master nodes and data nodes. The volume of data in these indices is huge around 100 million and we need to export them to relational DB.We are using elastic search client java library version 7.X.X

These indices are constantly been written by other applications, hence we decided to use search_after along with point in time (PIT).

We are fetching the data in loop with batch size of 100,000. After each hit to elastic search we insert the data in relation DB , extract sort information from hit and use it for next iteration. if after querying the hit count is zero we break out of loop and end the process.

Now the issue is that when I query the index _count API it returns X . And when I am fetching data in the application using the mechanism described above, results different results every time process.

I have no clue what could be the reason. There are no exception in the logs also. Kindly assist.

Comment: What are you sorting on? Is it guaranteed that the sort key that you use is unique?

Comment: We have id field which we are sorting on and yes it is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Is this id field used as elasticsearch id field? If yes, I would need more concrete information here to figure this one out. How does searching request look like? Which version of elasticsearch you are using? Have you tried logging and counting records as they come out of elasticsearch to make sure the issue is on the elasticsearch side?